# Why would a makefile recompile a class every time?

Tags: makefile, g++, recompile

Here's my makefile

```
all: main.o fileparam.o
        g++ -g $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS)  file_parameters.o main.o -o test
main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall $(INCPATH) main.cpp -c

fileparam.o: file_parameters.cpp file_parameters.h
        g++ -g -Wall file_parameters.cpp -c
```

$(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) points to the libraries to be included and $(INCPATH) points to other included files

For some reason it recompiles file_parameters.o every time I make the program, and I was wondering where I screwed up.  Thanks!

Edit: It does not recompile main.o every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
fileparam.o: file_parameters.cpp file_parameters.h
        g++ -g -Wall file_parameters.cpp -c
```

should be:

```
file_parameters.o: file_parameters.cpp file_parameters.h
        g++ -g -Wall file_parameters.cpp -c
```

Also, calling your output file `test` may cause confusion - change it to `mytest`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because your target, fileparam.o, is not generated by the rules... you're generating file_parameters.o instead. make sees the target doesn't exist, so it must build it.

Comment: Additionally, you might change the target "all" to "test", since that rule creates "test". If you don't do that, you'll re-link every time you run make.